# assert that type A is assignable to type B

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have type `T1` that I import from a 3rd party library. Assume type `T1` is defined as:

```
type T1 = {
    a: number | string
    b: 'b1' | 'b2' | 'b3'
    c?: boolean
}
```

Now I want to define type `T2` as follows:

```
type T2 = {
    a: number
    b: 'b1' | 'b2'
}
```

Objects of type `T2` can be used whenever a type `T1` is expected.

How can I explicitly assert that, at the point where T2 is defined, and have Typescript's type checker complain if this is not so?

I am expecting something like the following:

```
assert_assignable_to<T1, T2>()
```

I am assuming I can construct type `T2` from `T1` using combinations `Omit`, `Pick` and `&` but I want to explicitly assert in my code that instances of `T2` can be assigned to `T1`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a type generic. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDtIBNQNJAHgF0gJ3gIYA2oRsARrgbgJ4CwAUFjQA6SgDKAruc26AF5QAb0ahxoAgC5Q8LgFtyeUAB9QAZyy4EAczETyMgOTkAjEdWgTAJgtqTAZiP7xAYwD8M8gHtvRSATwjAC+jIwgoADqgVigWN6gSDAI7Ag4+MRENKAA7gAWsP6grnmQrgDWuqjQqFhG6pIaXGy4fJDhYG2czXhdQqIMERKSMnKKeB3DoIZWZnaztpOhDJMAQpB5fkgAhIyYLN6tcazsAMK4ATjcLW0A8tAAPNzk6NiQ8EgN13gANN0tAD5BP88ABuMKDMAAMQIhQasBq8G8sQITRuJ0YXW+rROwPOl0g2Luj2ebT+A2G0lkCiUuBc02Mc0sNmcDGCAKAA)

```js
// Defined in external library
type Subtype = {
    a: number | string
    b: 'b1' | 'b2' | 'b3'
    c?: boolean
}

// Want to define internally while checking if it's a supertype
// type Supertype = {
//     a: number
//     b: 'b1' | 'b2'
// }

// Behold!
export type CreateSupertypeOf<Sub extends Super, Super> = Super;

// Fails if not a supertype
type Supertype = CreateSupertypeOf<Subtype, {
    a: number
    b: 'b1' | 'b2'
}>
```

Note that in this example, `Suptype` is not assignable to `Supertype`. It seems you got your understanding of variance mixed up ([read more on variance and subtyping here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out)).

```
Type 'Subtype' does not satisfy the constraint '{ a: number; b: "b1" | "b2"; }'.
  Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

You probably meant this ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCVgEMbAMoCuKsywA8gGYA8hARnKLgHYAmAznIcQDSdHBQAfHAC8fYgG4AsAChZSFH1oLUYgN6y4WuFgBccJgQC2tAZu219AcloBGK3AA+cGwCYr5rQGMA-PtoQEAA22EyyAL7ypOICKqLomDj4-CQolDQEyqS8GjLaOvqGJgJOcGwwUACWTADmnnCWLnYOzm4tTQDMHjLhgkA)):

```js
type Subtype = {
    a: number
    b: 'b1' | 'b2'
    c?: boolean
}
type Supertype = CreateSupertypeOf<Subtype, {
    a: number | string
    b: 'b1' | 'b2' | 'b3'
}>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define `T2` to extend `T1`

```
interface T2 extends T1 {
    a: number
    b: 'b1' | 'b2'
}
```

in case `T2` is not assignable to `T1` you'll get an error

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gWAFBW1AhgLigDsBXAWwCMIAnKAHygGdhqBLIgc0xygsIHIKcfvSiCATCIaCAzP244AxgH5CFAPbqANhFxFMAX0yZ2wGgDNci6DHFQIADzNEAJo1gJ0WHAWLkq1ArYfGJCUqGShsYYphZWNjL2ThCu7vBePL6klDRBvAJhohLh-NTU8hhGGJiK6kTMUMBwhLZIqHm+cAA0eSGCwlHVGOYkRIrArHVQ5kQAFLjUHM0eAJSEAG7qrC7tQ1WYM7NNKwDcQA)

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is looking for? "T2 extends T1" will add all of T1 to T2, so in the example given it will add "c" to T2. If the library changes in future, more members may be added to T2 when that's not necessarily wanted or expected. I think the question is looking for an assertion that T2 as written is compatible with T1, without changing T2.